# Command `left`, `right`, and `justify`

Tags: ruby

```
line_width = 40
str = 'test'
puts (str.ljust(line_width))
puts (str.rjust(line_width))
puts (str.center(line_width))
puts (str.ljust(line_width)) + (str.rjust(line_width))
```

#### Output

```
test                                    
                                    test
                  test                  
test                                                                        test
```

Both the fourth line:

```
puts (str.rjust(line_width))
```

and the sixth line

```
puts (str.rjust(line_width))
```

have the same value `40`. Why are they printed in different locations?

Comment: What do you think `ljust`/`rjust` do? Explain in own words.

Comment: Try replacing `puts` by `p`, it will help you understand what the code is doing.

Comment: ljust = space from left? and rjust = space from right?

Comment: @steenslag has made a very good point. Also change `40` to `4` and play around with it. bear in mind that on the sixth line you're adding strings together, so you're adding the spaces too. i.e. `"test    " + "    test"  =  "test        test"` etc. Using puts will output without the quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

It's more obvious if you specify the "pad-string":

```
puts 'test'.ljust(40, '<')
puts 'test'.rjust(40, '>')
puts 'test'.center(40, '-')
puts 'test'.ljust(40, '<') + 'test'.rjust(40, '>')
```

Output:

```
test<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>test
------------------test------------------
test<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>test
```